# Run test cases through command line c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, command-line

Is there any way to run all test cases of a specific DLL through the command line? Also, can I catch the result of execution and find which test cases passed and which ones failed?

Comment: Which unit-testign framework do you use? I'm sure all frameworks have some console driver available.

Comment: any type of unit test

Comment: You mean "any type of test framework"? This will not be possible. But if you use e.g. nunit, the answer would be nunit3-console.exe

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on the testrunner, and unit testing framework.

For NET Core, you can generally run `dotnet test` in the same folder as your project file.

Take a look at the command line options of `dotnet.exe`to see the possible output options, so you can get something that works for you with regards to the test results.

Comment: Just a small note. `dotnet test` applicable not only for .NET Core projects but to all projects which been created with `dotnet new` command. In this case, `.csproj` will have a different structure and you can use `dotnet test` for projects targeting .Net framework as well